# Inheriting from Array

Tags: ecmascript-6, symbols

I am trying to inherit all of `Array`'s methods without using ES6 `class` syntactic sugar. Additionally, I want methods like `new MyArray().map()` to return instances of `MyArray`.

Simple illustration of my problem:

```
class MyArrayES6 extends Array{}

new MyArrayES6().slice() instanceof MyArrayES6 //true

function MyArray(){}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)
MyArray.prototype.constructor = MyArray
MyArray[Symbol.species] = MyArray //Doing this doesn't affect the outcome

new MyArray().slice() instanceof MyArray //false, to my suprise!
```

[A more complete code example](https://jsfiddle.net/jv457q76/1/)
edit: Gave clearer example

Comment: Lonely `So, ` at the end..?

Comment: Sadly, it perished of loneliness :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [ArraySpeciesCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrayspeciescreate) does not use @@species when the object is not an array.

And if you don't use `extends Array`, instances won't be arrays by default.

If you really want it to work, you can still return a real array with a modified [[Prototype]]:

```js
function ArraySub(){
  return Object.setPrototypeOf([], ArraySub.prototype);
}
ArraySub.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)
ArraySub.prototype.constructor = ArraySub
ArraySub[Symbol.species] = ArraySub;
console.log( new ArraySub().slice() instanceof ArraySub );
```

But that will hurt performance so bad. Better use `extends Array`.

Comment: Great answer. Does that entail that ES6 `class` offers more than just syntactical sugar? It seems like there is no good way to replicate that behavior without overriding the `Array` prototype, which does a lot more than simply hurt performance.
edit: scrap that, it just hurts performance

Comment: Better use `new.target.prototype` instead of `ArraySub.prototype` for proper subclassing. And don't forget to `Object.setPrototypeOf(ArraySub, Array)`.

Comment: @Batmoose Yes. Properly inheriting builtins is only possible with `class`  syntax.

Comment: The alternative to `setPrototypeOf` would be `Reflect.construct`, but that has the same availability issues that `class` does..

Comment: Great, thanks! This was somehow tricky to track down in the specs. As @loganfsmyth hinted, using `Reflect.construct` as follows would do the job as well: `function ArraySub(...args) {
    return Reflect.construct(Array, args, ArraySub);
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(ArraySub.prototype, Array.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(ArraySub, Array);
console.log(new ArraySub().slice() instanceof ArraySub); // true`